# How to add Bearer Token to SignalR HubConnection?

Tags: asp.net, azure, signalr

I have a bearer token that is using Azure AD tokens to authorize. Typically in signalR with .NET, you'd add a token like so:

```
hubConnection.Headers.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Authorization","Bearer " + result.AccessToken));
```

However, Azure uses this header in order to validate a connection to a web API, typically with the httpclient:

```
 var test = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
```

How can I add the AuthenticationHeaderValue to the signalR connection so that I can use Authorize'?

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, @tofutim. I ended up having my .NET azure API use *no* [Authorize] on the APi controller, but do use the Azure AD check in the Startup.Auth.cs of the API with a 'app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication'